# ZingChart pie tooltip not displaying

Tags: javascript, charts, zingchart

I have a pie ZingChart I'm using to show simple data. It happens to be using angular and updates the series object as the user drills down.

Everything is working fine except...the tooltip does not display? It doesn't display at any point, regardless of interaction or series assignment. The standard mouseover highlights work, and clicking nodes is fine, but no tooltip. Any ideas? Can't work out what I'm missing!
[image: Heres what it looks like]
My chart config is:

```
{
        type: "pie",
        id: 'chart-1',
        title: {
          textAlign: 'center',
          text: "Loading..."
        },
        "legend":{
          "border-width":1,
          "border-color":"gray",
          "border-radius":"5px",            
          "marker":{
            "type":"circle"
          },
          "toggle-action":"remove",
          "icon":{
            "line-color":"#9999ff"
          }
        },   
        "plot": {
          "animation":{
            "on-legend-toggle": true,
            "effect": 5,
            "method": 1,
            "sequence": 1,
            "speed": 0.7
          },
          "value-box": {
            "text": "$%v",
            "negation": "currency",
            "thousands-separator": ",",
            "font-color": "black",
            "placement":"in",
            "offset-r":"50%",
            "font-size":"12"            
          },
          "tooltip":{
            "text":"%t: %v (%npv%)"                
          },
          "decimals": "0",
          "detach": false
        },
        series: [],
        shapes: [{
          type: 'triangle',
          backgroundColor: '#66ccff',
          size: 10,
          angle: -90,
          x: 20,
          y: 20,
          cursor: 'hand',
          id: 'backwards'
        }]
      };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-` in `chart-1` is causing an issue with our parse/selector process. If you change the `id` to `chart_1` everything will work fine.

```js
var myConfig = {
"graphset":[
    {
        "type":"pie",
        "id":"chart_1",
        "title":{
            "textAlign":"center",
            "text":"Loading..."
        },
        "legend":{
            "border-width":1,
            "border-color":"gray",
            "border-radius":"5px",
            "marker":{
                "type":"circle"
            },
            "toggle-action":"remove",
            "icon":{
                "line-color":"#9999ff"
            }
        },
        "plot":{
            "animation":{
                "on-legend-toggle":true,
                "effect":5,
                "method":1,
                "sequence":1,
                "speed":0.7
            },
            "value-box":{
                "text":"$%v",
                "negation":"currency",
                "thousands-separator":",",
                "font-color":"black",
                "placement":"in",
                "offset-r":"50%",
                "font-size":"12"
            },
            "decimals":"0",
            "detach":false
        },
        "tooltip":{
            "text":"%t: %v (%npv%)"
        },
        "series":[
            {
                "values":[118],
                "text":"0-30"
            },
            {
                "values":[118],
                "text":"0-30"
            },
            {
                "values":[118],
                "text":"0-30"
            }
        ],
        "shapes":[
            {
                "type":"triangle",
                "backgroundColor":"#66ccff",
                "size":10,
                "angle":-90,
                "x":20,
                "y":20,
                "cursor":"hand",
                "id":"backwards"
            }
        ]
    }
]
};

zingchart.render({ 
 id: 'myChart', 
 data: myConfig, 
 height: '100%', 
 width: '100%' 
});
```

```css
html, body {
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
#myChart {
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 min-height:150px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src= "https://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js"></script>
  </head>
 <body>
  <div id="myChart"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```